# Get-SPweb with concatenated URL

Tags: powershell

I cant believe this isnt working, I must be blind!! Please help me...

When I do

```
$blog = Get-SPWeb http://sp01.domain.com:8080/my/personal/user1/Blog
```

it is working quite well, but

```
foreach ($site in (Get-SPSite http://sp01.domain.com:8080/my/personal/* -Limit ALL))
{
    $blog = Get-SPWeb "$site/Blog"
}
```

throws an Exception like "Cannot find an SPSite Object that contains the following ID or URL: http://sp01.domain.com:8080/my/personal/user1/Blog."

It concatenates the URL right but cant get the SPWeb-Object... I believe the solution must be freaking easy, but Im not very experienced with Powershell :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so PS is confused by you using your `SPSite`object as part of the URL, try this instead:

```
foreach ($site in (Get-SPSite http://sp01.domain.com:8080/my/personal/* -Limit ALL))
{
    $blog = Get-SPWeb ($site.Url + "/Blog") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($blog){
        #Do stuff here
    }
}
```

I notice also that not all of my Personal sites has a "Blog" web, so you should do some "if not null"-check on the `$blog` in the `foreach`.

Comment: You are right, I just realized the problem with the SPSite object myself a few seconds ago :D

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the ErrorAction and the check on $blog! :-)